# basic php else if not working

Tags: php, sql

I have some php validation for a user signup form. It's validating all the input then if all is correct the else at the end, checks to see if that username is in use and if not creates that record in the database. For some reason the last else doesn't get activated and it just refreshes with all the data still in the input boxes. I can't find the problem anywhere!!

```
if(isset($_POST['user']))
{
    $firstname = sanitiseString($_POST['firstname']); 
    $surname = sanitiseString($_POST['surname']);
    $user = sanitiseString($_POST['user']);
    $pass = sanitiseString($_POST['pass']);
    $email = sanitiseString($_POST['email']);
    $dateOfBirth = sanitiseString($_POST['dateOfBirth']);
    $gender = sanitiseString($_POST['gender']);

    $test_arr  = explode('-',$dateOfBirth);

    if($firstname == "" || $surname =="" || $user == "" || $pass == "" || $email == "" || $dateOfBirth == "" || $gender == "")
        {$error = "Not all fields were entered</br></br>";}
        else if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
            {$error = "Email format invalid</br></br>";}
        else if(count($test_arr) == 3) 
            {
            if (!checkdate($test_arr[0], $test_arr[1], $test_arr[2]))
                {$error = "Enter a date in the format: MM-DD-YYYY</br></br>";}
            }
        else if(count($test_arr) <> 3) 
            {$error = "Enter a date in the format: MM-DD-YYYY</br></br>";}
        else
            {
            $result = querySQL("SELECT * FROM members WHERE user='$user'");
            if($result->num_rows)
                {$error = "That Username already exists</br></br>";}
            else
                {
                querySQL("INSERT INTO members VALUES('','$firstname','$surname','$user','$pass','$email','$dateOfBirth','$gender')");
                die("<h4>Account Created</h4>Please Log In.</br></br>");
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Please, for God's sake use PDO!

Comment: chek what this code returns `$result->num_rows`

Comment: I think you should check this `$result->num_rows` against a value. something like `if($result->num_rows > 0)` rather than just 
`if($result->num_rows)`

Comment: I am choosing not to help because your curly braces make it frustrating to read the code.

Comment: Your logic's broken the first plain `else` is "unreachable", one of `count($test_arr) == 3` or `<> 3` must be satisified.

Comment: @Mat is completely correct in his observation that the `else` condition is unreachable.

Comment: Hooray! `If Else` still works. I was worried.

Comment: thought it was something silly. any suggestions on how to fix that neatly as its turned into a bit of a mess.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to comment on is the incredible amount of nested logic this script has; it's not uncommon to lose control of the flow when you're if / else branching gets out of control.

**Example Restructure**

```
if (isset($_POST['user']))
{
    // Prep
    $error = '';

    // Sanitize
    foreach( $_POST as $varName => $value )
    {
        // Doing this for minification on Stackoverflow
        $$varName = sanitiseString($_POST[$varName]);

        // Validate
        if ( empty($$varname) )
            $error .= "Not all fields were entered<br /><br />";
    }

    // Valid Email?
    if ( !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) )
        $error .= "Email format invalid<br /><br />";

    // Validate date
    $dateArray = explode('-', $dateOfBirth);
    if (!checkdate($dateArray[0], $dateArray[1], $dateArray[2]))
    {
        $error .= "Enter a date in the format: MM-DD-YYYY</br></br>";
    }

    $result = querySQL("SELECT * FROM members WHERE user='$user'");
    if ($result->num_rows)
    {
        $error .= "That Username already exists</br></br>";
    }

    if ( !empty($error) )
        die($error);

    querySQL("INSERT INTO members VALUES('','$firstname','$surname','$user','$pass','$email','$dateOfBirth','$gender')");
    die("<h4>Account Created</h4>Please Log In.</br></br>");
}
```

Some other things to note are conflicting logic with your `count($test_arr) == 3` and `count($test_arr) <> 3`.  And the value of `$result->num_rows` may not be 0, as your expecting.

Comment: Thanks that's much better! Also to Matt for pointing out the broken logic!